# How to enable my own custom OAuth external authorization with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am having a project in which i need to implement authorization using OAuth.

I am developing different apps with their different data.

Web app 1:
This is a SPA web app that will connect with a webAPI built for it that will expose related bussiness data to this web app.

Web app 2:
This is an MVC asp.net web site that also uses another web API built for it to get access to it's bussiness data.

My Auth service - this is what i want to know how to build:
What i need is to use asp identity and make a separate database and a separate web API that will handle authorization and authentication for the above web apps.

Web app 1 has it's own database and is using it's own web api to present data to users. So, is web app 2. This means that web app 1 does not depend, care or communicate in any way with web app 2. When a user of web app 1 or web app 2 wants to register or login he should communicate with web API of my auth service to do that. All my webapps should use the same auth service and be agnostic of it's specific details and only use this service's api for auth.

An example of this is google or facebook.

I am using c#, asp.net 5.

Any ideas or resources how to do this would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic implementation is included in Visual Studio 2015 templates. Choose new ASP.NET Web Application and then MVC or Web API with Individual User Accounts as Authentication option. MVC or Web API depending on the way you want to register and log in.

You have a more complete example with refresh tokens and managing different clientIds in the following [post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) by [Taiseer Joudeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625265/taiseer-joudeh), it's not ASP.NET 5 but I think it could be interesting for you.

Comment: Thank you. I found the same post also from Taiser and already implemented the solution i needed which seems to work fine for a starting point. More specifically it is the post http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/ but i would also suggest reading the previous posts to get s better understanding.